# I cannot route html homepages

Tags: node.js, router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
router.get('/', function(req, res){
 // res.sendFile('../views/main.html');
  res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../views/main.html'));
});
router.get('/location', function(req, res){
  res.render(path.join(__dirname,'../views/cafeLocation.html'));
});

router.get('/specificInfo', function(req, res){
  res.render(path.join(__dirname,'../views/cafeSpecificInfo.html'));
});

router.get('/personalInfo', function(req, res){
  res.render(path.join(__dirname,'../views/myPersonalInfo.html'));
});

router.get('/pointHistory', function(req, res){
  res.render(path.join(__dirname,'home/myPointHistory.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

I can only connect *router.get('/'* but other sites can't. the main site I can connect without problem. and other sites can't.  Is there problem to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in all your routes with this

```js
router.get('/pointHistory', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/home/myPointHistory.html'));
});
```

render method is just when you have a view engine like EJS or another

for ex.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.get('/privacy', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { view: 'privacy' })
});
```

Comment: I tried for all routes but only first one(mainpage) works.

Comment: what's you folder structure?, I think is a problem of the path

Comment: try without ../

Comment: all html files are in views folder